# Javascript IF used with OR

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, or-operator

I'm sure this is very easy and I've seen similar questions, but none have helped me figure out why this wont work.  Couldn't anyone tell me why this doesn't catch when `currentPage` is set as `faq` or `contact`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function init() {
                document.getElementById('searchSubmit').onclick=function(){
                        var uriArgs = window.location.search;
                        var currentPage = uriArgs.match(/page=?(\w*)/);
                        if ( (currentPage == null) || (currentPage == 'faq') || (currentPage == 'contact') ) {
                                currentPage = "index";
                                document.getElementById('searchHidden').value = currentPage;
                        }
                        else {
                                document.getElementById('searchHidden').value = currentPage[1];
                        }
                }
                }
                window.onload=init;
        </script>
```

I set an alert to popup so I could see whether or not it was properly being set as `faq` or `contact` and it was so I'm not sure why the `if` statement isn't catching that.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a match, [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return the capture group at index 1 of the array. Example:

```
> 'page=sdfsfsdf'.match(/page=?(\w*)/)
["page=sdfsfsdf", "sdfsfsdf"]
```

So you need to look *inside* of the array returned by `match` (assuming it is not `null`).

```
if (currentPage == null || currentPage[1] == 'faq' || currentPage[1] == 'contact') {
    /* ... */       
}
```

Comment: omg I don't know why this always happens to me, but I JUST realized that after I posted this question.  Thank you for the help.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the `if`-statement, but with the result of the [`match` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): It returns an array of the match and the matched groups - you want to compare to the first matched group.

```
var match = window.location.search = uriArgs.match(/page=?(\w*)/),
    currentPage = false;
if (match != null)
    currentPage = match[1];

if ( !currentPage || currentPage=='faq' || currentPage=='contact' ) {
    // do something
}
```